# Pandas : how to add Column name on dataframe on csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

new but excited about Python and i need your advice. I came up with the following code to compare two CSV files based on nmap scan:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import os
file = raw_input('\nEnter the Old CSV file: ')
file1 = raw_input('\nEnter the New CSV file: ')
A=set(pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False, header=None)[0])
B=set(pd.read_csv(file1, index_col=False, header=None)[0])
final=list(A-B)
df = pd.DataFrame(final, columns=["host"])
df.to_csv('DIFF_'+file)

print "Completed!"
```

when i run it i got the following results:
,

```
host
0,82.214.228.71;dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com;PTR;tcp;111;rpcbind;open;;;syn-ack;;3;
1,82.214.228.70;dsl-radius-01.direcpceu.com;PTR;tcp;111;rpcbind;open;;;syn-ack;;3;
```

My question is how to add a label/`enter code here`name on the columns 2,3 etc for example: hostanme , port , port name ,state etc.
I have tried :
df['hostname'] = range(1, len(df) + 1) but this adds the hostname on the first column along with host when i open the file with Excel

Comment: Do you want compare all columns or only first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameter `sep=','` and `names` for define columns names first:

```
file = raw_input('\nEnter the Old CSV file: ')
file1 = raw_input('\nEnter the New CSV file: ')

cols = ['hostname','port','portname', ...]
A= pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False, header=None, sep=';', names=cols)
B= pd.read_csv(file1, index_col=False, header=None, sep=';', names=cols)
```

Then use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with comparing by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) if need compare all columns:

```
df = pd.merge(A, B, how='outer', indicator=True)
df = df[df['_merge']=='left_only'].drop('_merge',axis=1)

df.to_csv('DIFF_'+file)

print "Completed!"
```

**Sample**:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""82.214.228.71;dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com;PTR;tcp;111;rpcbind;open;;;syn-ack;;3;
82.214.228.70;dsl-radius-01.direcpceu.com;PTR;tcp;111;rpcbind;open;;;syn-ack;;3;
82.214.228.74;dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com;PTR;tcp;111;rpcbind;open;;;syn-ack;;3;
82.214.228.75;dsl-radius-01.direcpceu.com;PTR;tcp;111;rpcbind;open;;;syn-ack;;3;"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
cols = ['hostname','port','portname', 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i', 'j']
A = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", names=cols)
print (A)
        hostname                         port portname    a    b        c  \
0  82.214.228.71  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
1  82.214.228.70  dsl-radius-01.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
2  82.214.228.74  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
3  82.214.228.75  dsl-radius-01.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   

      d   e   f        g   h  i   j  
0  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN  
1  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN  
2  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN  
3  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN
```

---

```
temp=u"""82.214.228.75;dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com;PTR;tcp;111;rpcbind;open;;;syn-ack;;3;
82.214.228.70;dsl-radius-01.direcpceu.com;PTR;tcp;111;rpcbind;open;;;syn-ack;;3;
82.214.228.77;dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com;PTR;tcp;111;rpcbind;open;;;syn-ack;;3;
"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
cols = ['hostname','port','portname', 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i', 'j']
B = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", names=cols)
print (B)
        hostname                         port portname    a    b        c  \
0  82.214.228.75  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
1  82.214.228.70  dsl-radius-01.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
2  82.214.228.77  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   

      d   e   f        g   h  i   j  
0  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN  
1  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN  
2  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN
```

---

```
df1 = pd.merge(A, B, how='outer', indicator=True)

print (df1)

        hostname                         port portname    a    b        c  \
0  82.214.228.71  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
1  82.214.228.70  dsl-radius-01.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
2  82.214.228.74  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
3  82.214.228.75  dsl-radius-01.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
4  82.214.228.75  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
5  82.214.228.77  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   

      d   e   f        g   h  i   j      _merge  
0  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN   left_only  
1  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN        both  
2  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN   left_only  
3  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN   left_only  
4  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN  right_only  
5  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN  right_only
```

```
#only values in A
df1 = df1[df1['_merge']=='left_only'].drop('_merge',axis=1)
print (df1)
        hostname                         port portname    a    b        c  \
0  82.214.228.71  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
2  82.214.228.74  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
3  82.214.228.75  dsl-radius-01.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   

      d   e   f        g   h  i   j  
0  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN  
2  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN  
3  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN
```

```
#only values in B
df1 = pd.merge(A, B, how='outer', indicator=True)
df11 = df1[df1['_merge']=='right_only'].drop('_merge',axis=1)
print (df11)
        hostname                         port portname    a    b        c  \
4  82.214.228.75  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
5  82.214.228.77  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   

      d   e   f        g   h  i   j  
4  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN  
5  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN
```

```
#same values in both dataframes
df12 = df1[df1['_merge']=='both'].drop('_merge',axis=1)
print (df12)
        hostname                         port portname    a    b        c  \
1  82.214.228.70  dsl-radius-01.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   

      d   e   f        g   h  i   j  
1  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN
```

---

But if need compare only first column `hostname` use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for mask, `~` for inverting with `boolean indexing`:

```
df2 = A[~A['hostname'].isin(B['hostname'])]
print (df2)
        hostname                         port portname    a    b        c  \
0  82.214.228.71  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   
2  82.214.228.74  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com      PTR  tcp  111  rpcbind   

      d   e   f        g   h  i   j  
0  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN  
2  open NaN NaN  syn-ack NaN  3 NaN
```

Comment: hey Jez.Thanks! WIll try as well and get back

Comment: Yes, sure. small notice - if csv has csv header also, remove parameter `header=None` and parametr `names`

Comment: Perfect Jez! worked like a  charm! Had just to add  sep=';' on the writing statement : df.to_csv('DIFF_'+file , sep=';') and i got what i wanted :).I am accpeting this answer and just one more thing if you dont mind. I am getting  the following:
             host                     hostname hostname_type protocol port  \
24  82.214.228.70  dsl-radius-01.direcpceu.com           PTR      tcp  111   
32  82.214.228.71  dsl-radius-02.direcpceu.com           PTR      tcp  111

Comment: Super, glad can help!

Comment: you guys make my Python journey much easier and learning so much from you :).BTW  can i get right off the index column ..In this case the row numbers?..

Comment: if need remove index for to_csv simply add `df.to_csv('DIFF_'+file , sep=';', index=False) `

Comment: was thinking the same ..:).All set ! Thank you

Comment: hope you can help one question.How to exclude both on the _merge and get both left-only and right_only in the file? .Is there a way?

Comment: I think simpliest is change condition.

Comment: `df1['_merge']=='both'` to `df1['_merge']!='both'` for select right or left only.

Comment: you saved my day! .i 'thought' i was trying it but just figured that i made a typo   : i   had df1['_merge'] !=='both'..(double ==) thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the labels where you are defining the dataframe. For example, the following should work

```
df = pd.DataFrame(final, columns=["host"].append([x for x in range(1, len(df) + 1)] ))
```

Comment: Thanks Amit! Will try and get back